# Resque Worker: invalid operator: $oid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, resque

A worker that was working a few days ago has ceased to work for some reason.

The resque log reports an exception of `Mongo::OperationFailure` with the error`invalid operator: $oid`

```
class SimilarTargets
  @queue = :similar_queue

  def self.perform(target_id)
    source_target = Target.find(target_id)

    ....

  end
end
```

The worker is failing on Target.find(target_id), even when a straight string is passed in via the rails console.

Target.find(id) works fine in the console and elsewhere in the code and I can't figure out why this has failing even though the worker class has never changed in the last week.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you upgrade Mongoid recently? The error makes it sound like the .find() method is receiving something like `{"$oid": "[STRING]"}`, which is the strict json representation of an Object ID for Mongo.

You can get around it with something like this, assuming you just want a quick fix:

```
target_id = target_id["$oid"] unless target_id.is_a?(String)
```

Comment: I ran into this issue too, do you know why it's doing this? I'm having weird inconsistent behavior with creating Resque jobs with mongoid object ids. My app is a Sinatra app, and in one request handler it creates a new Resque job that takes a mongoid document's ID as a parameter. This job works fine, the id just gets serialized as the string. However, this job, when it finishes, queues up another job, passing in the same object's id to the next job, and for some reason this second job gets the JSON version of the ObjectID instead of just the string. Both jobs are queued the same way.

Comment: As MrKurt said Moped::BSON::ObjectId serializes to JSON as "{\"$oid\": \"#{to_s}\"}". When Resque is dumping a Object Id to its payload, to_json is called on the ObjectId resulting in this being stored and marshalled when the job is later executed.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to ensure that when you enqueue a Moped::BSON::ObjectId you explicitly pass in a string representation. E.g.,

```
Resque.enqueue(MyJob, @mongoid_instance.class.to_s, @mongoid_instance.id.to_s)
```